# Nextpeer issues

Tags: nextpeer

I am wondering if anyone can help out with some issues of integrating nextpeer into my game.

1. First off, it appears when the game is complete and the nextpeer windo is supposed to appear, there is a little bit of a lag that can last from 3-7 seconds long. When that happens the game sits in somewhat of a frozen state and the user can't do anything. I have seen this happening in other games, so I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on what to do.
2. I have the player 2 player integration setup where you can see other players characters in the game. Basically you know where their position is in reference to yours. My problem is that I only see the other player if it is an actual other player as apposed to one of the bots or fake players they have that you play against. According to nextpeer you should see the bots as well not just real players.

Also the other players move slowly, meaning you really don't see them other than in the beginning.

Thanks!

Comment: In its current form, your question is not really suitable for StackOverflow. Please read the [faq] to learn what kind of questions should be asked.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

First, make sure you're using the latest SDK [1.4.5](http://developers.nextpeer.com/downloads/sdk)

You should send small size messages and lower the frequency of your messages:

From [Nextpeer FAQ](http://developers.nextpeer.com/faq/faq#PlayertoPlayer):

Q. How often should should I send updates? How many should I send? What is the recommended file capacity?

**A. We recommend you don't send more than 10 updates per second and have them be no more than roughly 500 bytes.**